# actionmailer not sending emails even after setting all the possible configurations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the method inside **ApplicationMailer**

```
class CancelTrip < ApplicationMailer
    default from: 'xyz@gmail.com'

    def cancel_trip
        @recvr= "ssdd@gmail.com"
        mail(to: @recvr, subject: 'Your trip has been cancelled as per your request' )
    end
end
```

And the environmental variables as follows:

```
SMTP_ADDRESS: 'smtp.gmail.com'
SMTP_PORT: 587
SMTP_DOMAIN: 'localhost:3000'
SMTP_USERNAME: 'xyz@gmail.com'
SMTP_PASSWORD: 'gggh2354'
```

And I am call the mailer method in my controller as follows:

```
def cancel
   xxxxx
   CancelTrip.cancel_trip.deliver_now
end
```

**developement.rb** has following

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'localhost', port:3000}
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Log shows the email being sent. But I dont see any email in inbox. 
My rails version is 4.2.6.

Answer (score 1):

Add following smtp setting on `config/application.rb` file:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port => 587,
      :domain => "gmail.com",
      :user_name => "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
      :password => "xxxxxxxx",
      :authentication => "plain",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in junk mail... I had this problem a little while back

Comment: Have you checked junk mail?

Comment: I did already. I checked the spam folder. I didnt receive it there either.

Answer (score 0):

use [letter opener](https://github.com/fgrehm/letter_opener_web) in development for be sure your actionmailer delivered your mail. after that you can finding deliver error to gmail or other.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `ApplicationMailer` is inheriting from `ActionMailer::Base.`

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'from@exmaple.com'
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility may be your firewall not allows to send email. Try connect different network.